# Using the Author field of R Markdown in footer.html

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

R Markdown allows to add a footer to your html output. The YAML header allows to give an author name using a specific field.

I would like to use this author name in my footer.html file, but cannot figure out how to achieve that.

Here is a minimal example:

`fic.rmd`:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "Mister-A"
output:
  html_document:
    include:
      after_body: footer.html
---

content
```

And in the same folder the `footer.html` file:

```
I am - @author-name-field-that-I-don't-konw-how-to-get -
```

Any help or advice would me much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the YAML parameters within sections of the report, you need to alter the base pandoc template. You can find all of them [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/)

The basic structure of making this work is to put the variable surrounded by dollar signs to use the YAML variable in the output document. So for example `$author$` is required in this case.

### Solution

We can create a copy of the pandoc template for HTML in our local directory using the following command. This is the same file as [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.html5).

```
# Copies the RMkarkdown template to the local directory so we can edit it
file.copy(rmarkdown:::rmarkdown_system_file("rmd/h/default.html"), to = "template.html")
```

In the template.html, we need to add the pandoc tags. To add a footer, we want to add code to the buttom of the document. This is line 457 in the current template but this may change in future versions, so we want to put it after the `include-after` tag:

```
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$
$endfor$

<hr />
<p style="text-align: center;">I am $author$</p>

$if(theme)$

$if(toc_float)$
</div>
</div>
$endif$
```

Finally, the R Markdown file looks like:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "Mister-A"
output:
  html_document:
    template: template5.html
---

This is some text
```

[image]

As a possible extension of this, you may want to check out [this post](https://holtzy.github.io/Pimp-my-rmd/) on designing a stylish footer.

Comment: Btw I just put two and two together and realised I shared your own blog with you :D good work.

Comment: Yes I was quite glad about that :). Thx again!